# Anaconda distribution of pytables is broken

Tags: python, pytables, anaconda, conda

I just switched to the anaconda distribution of python, and I'm having trouble with a few packages. One example is pytables:

```
~$ ipython
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 17 2014, 10:13:17) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import tables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-389ecae14f10> in <module>()
----> 1 import tables

/nfs/slac/g/ki/ki18/anja/awright/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/__init__.py in <module>()
     80 
     81 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the cython extension
---> 82 from tables.utilsextension import (get_pytables_version, get_hdf5_version,
     83     getPyTablesVersion, getHDF5Version)  # Pending Deprecation!
     84 

ImportError: /nfs/slac/g/ki/ki18/anja/awright/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so: undefined symbol: H5Pset_file_image
```

I tried to fix the problem, but it's not happening. This package was working with my previous python distribution, so it's not like my computer is incompatible. Can anyone offer some advice?

Here is what I've already tried to do:

```
~$ conda list tables
# packages in environment at /nfs/slac/g/ki/ki18/anja/awright/anaconda:
#
# Warning: subprocess call to pip failed
pytables                  3.0.0                np17py27_1  
~$ conda search tables
pytables                 2.4.0                np16py26_0  defaults        
                         2.4.0                np16py27_0  defaults        
                         2.4.0                np17py26_0  defaults        
                         2.4.0                np17py27_0  defaults        
                         3.0.0                np16py26_0  defaults        
                         3.0.0                np16py27_0  defaults        
                         3.0.0                np17py26_0  defaults        
                         3.0.0                np17py27_0  defaults        
                         3.0.0                np16py26_1  defaults        
                         3.0.0                np16py27_1  defaults        
                         3.0.0                np17py26_1  defaults        
                      *  3.0.0                np17py27_1  defaults        
                         3.0.0                np17py33_1  defaults        
~$ conda update tables
Error: package 'tables' is not installed in /nfs/slac/g/ki/ki18/anja/awright/anaconda
~$ conda install tables
Error: No packages found matching: tables
~$ conda install pytables
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /nfs/slac/g/ki/ki18/anja/awright/anaconda:
#
pytables                  3.0.0                np17py27_1  
~$ conda update pytables
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /nfs/slac/g/ki/ki18/anja/awright/anaconda:
#
pytables                  3.0.0                np17py27_1
```

Comment: I think it is pretty well known that certain packages and in particular PyTables are broken in Anaconda right now.  I have always had to install HDF5 and PyTables by hand on top of my Anaconda.  Not the most satisfying solution.  I would try bringing this up on the conda mailing list: conda@continuum.io

Comment: A better place would be the anaaconda mailing list, anaconda@continuum.io. The conda mailing list should only be for things specific to the conda package manager.